# Resolving dependencies using OwinContext vs using a DI container like Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, owin

In one of my web applications, I am currently using OwinContext to obtain service and repository dependencies in  the MVC controllers. Should I continue to do this or should I better start using a full fledged DI container like Unity?